# GPX files won't load in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location, gpx

**Summary:**

I've tried loading GPX files into the Android emulator, but I get the error message "The table contains errors.  No locations were sent".

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open emulator
2. Tap on three dots in right vertical strip
3. In "Extended controls" popup under the "Location" tab, click "LOAD GPX/KML" and select a GPX file
4. Click "Play" button

[image: Emulator Location]

GPX file (test.gpx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version="1.1"
creator="gpx-poi.com">
   <wpt lat="28.0587" lon="-82.4139">
      <time>2015-12-01T03:01:44Z</time>
   </wpt>
</gpx>
```

**Expected behavior:**

Location should be sent to the emulator

**Observed behavior:**

Error message "The table contains errors.  No locations were sent":

[image]

**Device and Android version:**

Emulator Nexus 5X API Level 23 (Google APIs), 1080 x 1920; 420 dpi, Android 6.0 (Google APIs), x86, 1GB on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of August 10, 2016, it looks like the emulator does not support the GPX waypoint format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version="1.1"
creator="gpx-poi.com">
   <wpt lat="28.0587" lon="-82.4139">
      <time>2015-12-01T03:01:44Z</time>
   </wpt>
</gpx>
```

However, it does seem to support the GPX track format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version="1.1"
creator="gpx-poi.com">
   <trk>
      <name />
      <cmt />
      <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="28.0587" lon="-82.4139">
          <ele>0</ele>
          <time>2015-12-01T03:01:44Z</time>
        </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
</gpx>
```

The above GPX track format successfully loads into the emulator and properly injects the location.